# How to create a desktop shortcut to an existing session in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I saved a session in notepad++ and I know how to load that session from notepad++ using the "Load Session..." option.  But how do I create a shortcut to open that session when notepad++ starts?  My eventual end case is that I will have several shortcuts that I will open using Launchy depending on which session I want to work on.

Comment: The way I make changes to session files is to copy the session file to something with a different extension (e.g. .txt) and then edit the txt file. When I'm done, I can rename the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the Answer:  In Notepad++ (5.6.8 in my case)

1. Setting -> Preferences.
2. Miscellaneous Tab
3. enter an extension for Session files.  I entered **nps**
   (without a dot)
4. Now Notepad++ is aware of session files. and will open the files contained in the
   session file's xml entries.

For example, a file called nyssis-session.nps has the contents:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <Session activeView="0">
        <mainView activeIndex="1">
            <File firstVisibleLine="147" xOffset="0" scrollWidth="960" startPos="6065" endPos="6065" selMode="0" lang="Java" encoding="-1" filename="C:\Dev\ws\AuditJobAndPollForCompletion.java" />
            <File firstVisibleLine="48" xOffset="0" scrollWidth="624" startPos="2277" endPos="2277" selMode="0" lang="Java" encoding="-1" filename="C:\Dev\ws\StartBatchJobAndPoll.java" />
            <File firstVisibleLine="33" xOffset="0" scrollWidth="872" startPos="2331" endPos="2331" selMode="0" lang="Java" encoding="-1" filename="C:\Dev\ws\LoadMatchResultTable.java" />
        </mainView>
        <subView activeIndex="0" />
    </Session>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Opening this file will now open the three files (not the xml definition - in fact if I want to manually edit this file I need to open it with something other than NotePad++).